# Can a spring mvc rest endpoint map to 2 different urls like /users.json and /users.xml?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm creating  a java rest endpoing, and consuming it using Ruby.

In the ruby/rails world, using Active Resource, the urls can be either:

```
/users.json
```

or

```
/users.xml
```

Currently my controller method looks like:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/users.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

}
```

I don't want to have to duplicate this method for mapping to the url with the .xml extension.

**Can I do both urls somehow?**

I also have to set the content type to either json or xml also.

I know the other way is for spring to look at the request header and then return either json or xml, but it seems for me to mimick how rails works I need to have users.json or users.xml (based on the url structure as oppose to the request header).

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible with Spring's `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`. See this how-to blog post: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/

Answer (score 1):

when using @ResponseBody you will bypass ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.

let your url be /users instead of /users.json or /users.xml and set your Accept header in requestheaders to desired mediatype, framework will select appropriate messageconverter and does the job for you. 
Note: messageconverter  should be present in your classpath.

Hope this helps.